Is it possible to create a REST API that generates a customizable installer based on a POST request using Docker?
I'm developing a REST API that needs to generate a customizable installer (either a .exe or .msi) based on the content of a POST request. The request contains a POCO with various attributes, and the installer should:
Download specific files as indicated by the attributes of the POCO.
Place these files in designated folders on a Windows system.
The idea is to automate the creation of an installer based on the parameters provided in the POST request. It's crucial that this process runs in a Docker container, as I need the solution to be as decoupled as possible and scalable for future use.
My questions are:
Is it feasible to achieve this using Docker in the context of a REST API?
What would be the best approach or existing tools to handle the generation of the installer (i.e., .exe or .msi) in such an environment?
Any insights or guidance on how to structure this would be greatly appreciated!
